# Saving and loading drawing in FirefoxOS using local storage

Tags: javascript, indexeddb, firefox-os

I'm trying to make an drawing application for FirefoxOS. Recently, i tried using indexedDB for local storage. However, since the app has to save a lot of coordinates in order to load them when starting the app the other day, indexedDB is giving me an error ABORTERROR (though only a part of drawn picture is displayed on restarting the app). I tried this in Firefox 21.0.

I would like to know how the procedure goes for saving and loading such things. I'm using Android S3 which has a similar App called S Memo which does similar stuff. The app has to be written in HTML and JavaScript because I want to use it with FirefoxOS.

Comment: is it possible that the app/phone shutdown during a write operation? [IndexedDB asynchronous operations fail to complete when browser is closed](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=870645)

Comment: thanks, but i don't think that indexedDB is capable of serving a huge data at a very high rate. When i put some delay, it runs fine but when frequency is high ABORTERROR !

Comment: How are you saving your coordinates in the database? What schema/organization are you using?

Comment: We use IDB extensively for the core apps and store significant amounts of data without problem.  If you are getting ABORTERROR simply from the data rate or size, then please file a bug as we should fix that!  It would be helpful to see the code, however, as its possible something else is going on.  You could also try the async_storage wrapper we use here:  https://github.com/mozilla-b2g/gaia/blob/master/shared/js/async_storage.js

Answer (score 0):

You may like to save bunch of coordinates into single json or blob when lose visibility, therefore the loading will be faster and then the indexedDB is not blocked by frequent read/write operations.